# Nested IFs in SPSS

Tags: if-statement, nested, spss

Is it possible to nest conditional statements in SPSS?

The following did not work for me:

```
    DO IF (t = resultcodeid)

        DO IF t = 1
            COMPUTE hits = r.
        END IF.

        DO IF t = 2
            COMPUTE misses = r.
        END IF.

    END IF.
```

Comment: It is possible, see the [help](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_do_if_nested_do_if_structures.htm). More details will be needed to give any better advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DO IF can certainly be nested.  Note that each statement needs to be terminated by a period.

Also, since the inner ones are alternatives, it would be cleaner to write that as
do if t = 1.
...
else if t = 2.
...
end if.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Answer (score 1):

```
   #YOU CAN USE THIS PROCESS:

          DO IF (t = resultcodeid)

         DO IF t = 1
        COMPUTE hits = r.

    ELSE IF t = 2
        COMPUTE misses = r.
    ELSE IF T=3
   COMPUTE  misses=r.
  ELSE IF .......


END IF.
EXECUTE.
```